# .NET compact framework - barcode scanner

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, barcode

I have Motorola MC55 with Windows Mobile 6.5 on-board. This nice palm contains also an embedded bar-code scanner. My question is - Will I need anything special in .NET CF in order to  use the bar-code scanner? I would expect that the bar-code are read as normal strings and delivered as keyboard events? Is any special .NET CF library necessary?

Thanks for help

Dominik

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That entirely depends on what you want to achieve.

Handheld barcode scanners based on Windows Mobile usually come with a piece of software that translates barcode module output to keystrokes -- you can put it in the autorun folder and then handle text input in your textbox.

Alternatively, there's usually an SDK that contains libraries with which you can hook the scanner directly and have all the additional information (type of the barcode, binary data etc).

We use MC9090 here, and we went the SDK way. Works like a charm. The SDK can be dowloaded [here](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=12623&sliceId=&dialogID=177686738). If the link doesn't work (I had to crop it), go to the [seach form](http://support.symbol.com/support/searchEntry.do?languages=&rwTarget=%2FrfPlayerWidget.do&searchMode=GuidedSearch&searchString=SDK&productLine=SG_MOBILECOMPUTERS_1_1&product=SG_MC55_1_2&document=DT_SOFTWARE_1_1&cmd=search&productFamily=&contextType=gs) and search for "SDK".

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is the way I'll go.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, for Motorola (earlier Symbol) scanners there's a set of libraries for the Comapact Framework including samples.

We use mobile devices a lot with our customers (not only Motorola) and I strongly advise against using keyboard emulation if possible, as you will run into trouble when there are multiple input fields (or no input fields at all). Also, you will not be able to detect special characters within barcodes when you get them through keyboard emulation.

Link to SDK is provided by GSerg in his answer. I strongly recommend using the SDK as it provides access to other device functionality as well.

Comment: Very true - don't underestimate the ability to disable the scanner when you don't need the input!

Answer (score 3):

There's a utility for these devices called [DataWedge](http://support.symbol.com/support/browse.do?WidgetName=BROWSE_PRODUCT&TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&BROWSE_PRODUCT.isProductTaxonomy=true&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeId=SG_MC55_1_2&BROWSE_PRODUCT.thisPageUrl=%2Fproduct%2Fproducts.do&id=m4&BROWSE_PRODUCT.TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&NodeType=leaf&NodeName=MC55&document=DT_PRODUCTMANUALS_1_1&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeType=leaf&NodeId=SG_MC55_1_2&AppContext=AC_ProductPage&param_document=sp) that lets you treat the built-in scanner as a keyboard device.